# How to scan and verify the version of TLS for a website?

Tags: c#, ssl

How to scan and verify the version of TLS for a website?

I was hunting for solutions which can automatically scan all the endpoint website domain in our company. SSL Labs had a manual online solution

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html

How can this feature be achieved programmatically?

Comment: Your question is too broad as is without any specific code question. "How to scan and verify the version of TLS for a website?" You connect as a TLS client using various parameters and you study the TLS server reply. It depends on what exactly you need to test. https://testssl.sh/ is an example, is another https://github.com/noxxi/p5-ssl-tools/blob/master/analyze-ssl.pl. Even if you do not use them as is, it gives you idea on what to test and how.

Comment: You should be able to simply use `SslStream` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. Created free and open-source project on GitHub https://github.com/JocysCom/SslScanner, which contains:

- Portable standalone SSL, TLS, STARTTLS Scanner Tool.
- /Tool/Common/Test_SSL_Support.cs - C# code which will check SSL/TLS version
- /Tool/Common/Test_SSL_Support.bat - simple batch script which runs C# like a script on Windows Command Line. Note: I use PowerShell and Batch on Windows to run C# like a scripting language in order to automate tons of stuff.

Test_SSL_Support.cs have 'TestTCP' method which returns 'true' if connection supports specified protocol version:

```
static bool TestTCP(string host, int port, SslProtocols protocol, out bool connected)
{
    var success = false;
    var client = new TcpClient();
    var asyncResult = client.BeginConnect(host, port, null, null);
    // 5 seconds timeout.
    connected = asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    // Connected.
    if (connected)
    {
        var stream = client.GetStream();
        // Don't dispose underlying stream.
        using (var sslStream = new SslStream(stream, true, ValidateServerCertificate))
        {
            sslStream.ReadTimeout = 15000;
            sslStream.WriteTimeout = 15000;
            sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(host, null, protocol, false);
            result.UpdateFromSslStream(sslStream);
            success = true;
        }
        client.EndConnect(asyncResult);
    }
    return success;
}
```

Test_SSL_Support.cs supports StartTLS protocol too. Look for method:

```
static bool TestStarTLS(string host, int port, SslProtocols protocol, out bool connected)
```

You can add multiple hosts and ports to Test_SSL_Support.bat for scan:

```
:: Test SSL/TLS.
CALL:PS www.google.com 443
:: Test StartTLS.
CALL:PS mail.jocys.com 110
```

Command line results are represented as:

```
172.217.169.4 www.google.com:443

  Ssl2  = False | The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm
  Ssl3  = False | The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm
  Tls   = True  | Exchange = ECC-256 | Cipher = AES128 | Hash = SHA1
  Tls11 = True  | Exchange = ECC-256 | Cipher = AES128 | Hash = SHA1
  Tls12 = True  | Exchange = ECC-256 | Cipher = AES128 | Hash = SHA256
  Tls13 = True  | Exchange = ECC-256 | Cipher = AES256 | Hash = SHA384

62.30.149.144 mail.jocys.com:110

  Ssl2  = False | The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm
  Ssl3  = False | The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm
  Tls   = False | Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
  Tls11 = False | Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
  Tls12 = True  | Exchange = ECC-384 | Cipher = AES256 | Hash = SHA384
  Tls13 = False | Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
```

Answer (score 0):

SSLLabsAPI seems to work

```
using SslLabsLib.Enums;
using SslLabsLib;

public static void TLSChecker(string urlString)
{

    SslLabsClient client = new SslLabsClient();                                 
    // Get ipaddress and host
    var analysis = client.GetAnalysis(urlString, 24, AnalyzeOptions.Publish);
    Console.WriteLine(analysis.Host);            

    foreach (var item in analysis.Endpoints)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.IpAddress);

       var endpointanalysis = client.GetCachedEndpointAnalysis(analysis.Host, IPAddress.Parse(item.IpAddress));

        // get protocol list
        foreach (var protocol in endpointanalysis.Details.Protocols)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(protocol.Id);
            Console.WriteLine(protocol.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(protocol.Version);                    
        }                

    }
```

Comment: This just makes SSLabs do the test, and you retrieve the results. It is different from the fact of you doing the test. This is not clear from your question. If your server are internal for example and not reachable from Internet, using SSLabs API or anyone else won't help you.

Comment: Agree that this question body/answer pair is misleading. You are not "programmingly" scan/verify a server by yourself, but relying on a third party service, which can be unavailable in many cases. However, like I commented above, .NET built-in class `SslStream` can get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Use HttpClient... force it to use TLS 1.2... see if it fails... profit.

```
public async Task<bool> SupportsTls12(string url)
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    var client = new HttpClient();
    try
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        return true;
    }
    catch(HttpRequestException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you find this gives you false positive/negatives, you may have to modify the exception handler to inspect the specific error that is returned. But this is the general idea.